# Different variables for different request in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

Say, I have the following code (Assume all undefined functions as async tasks which return promise):

```
app.post('/abc', (req, res) => {
    var project;
    getProject(req.body.projectId)
        .then((_projectData) => {
            //this data is required by other functions in this promise chain
            project = _projectData;
        })
        .then(()=>{
             return doSomething1(project)
         })
        .then(()=>{
             return doSomething2(project)
         })
        .then(()=>{
             return doSomething3(project)
         })
        .then(()=>{
             return res.status(200).send('Everything done.')
         })
        .catch((err) => {
             return res.status(500).send('Error occured.')
        })
});
```

Now, when a request came, the project will be set to the project data related to that request. And doSomething1() will be called. Say, doSomething1() is taking a lot of time. Meanwhile second request came and getProject() called, and then the project variable would change. Now when 2nd request's doSomething1() is executing, 1st request's doSomething1() is completed and doSomething2() get called, but with the different project variable.

How to avoid this situation?
What is the best case for such cases?

(One way could be to break this promise chain into 2 promise chains, and put all the dependents in one chain, so that each request has different scope of project variable and all other functions are called in that scope:

```
app.post('/abc', (req, res) => {
    getProject(req.body.projectId)
        .then((_projectData) => {
            //this data is required by other functions in this promise chain
            var project = _projectData;
            doSomething1(project).
               .then(()=>{
                   return doSomething2(project)
               })
               .then(()=>{
                   return doSomething3(project)
               })
              .then(()=>{
                  return res.status(200).send('Everything done.')
               })
               .catch((err) => {
                    return res.status(500).send('Error occured.')
               })
            })
        .catch((err) => {
             return res.status(500).send('Error occured.')
        })
});
```

But this doesn't seems good, as if the promise chain is big, and there are more dependencies (like output of doSomething1() as input of doSomething3()), the promise chains won't work as they are designed to.

Another way could be to pass the project variable via each promise resolve, but it would not be possible, as it might be 3rd party module function, or even changing the return value of a function for that purpose would not justify the function re-usability.)

What am I missing here?

Comment: The specified things can be achieved more easily using nodejs async module. Have a look at that.

Comment: @Inventillect that would not help at all and is mostly unrelated to the question asked. Did you even read it?

Comment: Manish, what you are describing isn't what happens, every time the route handler is called it has a different value for `project` because that's how closures work. If you wanted them to use the same variable you would have defined it outside of the function. That is, your original code should work as expected (Although it's a little clumsy and I'd do it differently)

Comment: You can easily have output of one function as input to another function. There are methods for that. have a look for example at asyn.waterfall method

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum thanks for the explanation.. I got it..

Comment: @Inventillect which is what he already has with promises, that's literally how promises work - async is mostly deprecated with the functionality being in the language itself now through promises.